# If $a,b,c$ are real numbers all less than or equal to $1$ such that $a+b+c=0$ , then is it true that $(1-a)(1-b)(1-c) \le 1$?

Tags: inequality

If $a,b,c$ are real numbers all less than or equal to $1$  such that $a+b+c=0$ , then is it true that $(1-a)(1-b)(1-c) \le 1$ ? I tried Weierstrass inequality but noticed that $a,b,c$ might all not be greater than $1$ , please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $a,b,c\le1$, we have $1-a,1-b,1-c\ge0$, so by [AM-GM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means),
$$(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)\le\left((1-a)+(1-b)+(1-c)\over3\right)^3=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Except for the trivial case $a=b=c=0$, at least one of the 3 numbers $a,b,c$ is positive and at least one is negative. Except for a permutation, we can assume that $a>0,b<0$ and hence $ab<0$. Then
$$(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)\leq(1-a-b)(1-c)=(1+c)(1-c)=1-c^2\leq1.$$
Another proof uses that $1+x\leq e^x$ for all real $x$. Hence
$$(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)\leq e^{-a}e^{-b}e^{-c}=e^{-a-b-c}=e^0=1.$$